# How could I create an autocomplete search field in a plugin Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to create a plugin (doctor-plugin) for Wordpress and I want to use this plugin for a shortcode [doctors-info] only in one page.

So I already have one array in my plugin file (doctor-plugin.php), like:

```
$doctor = Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Anthony Smith
        [specialities] => Array
            (
                [6] => Speciality 6
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Name Doctor
        [specialities] => Array
            (
                [7] => Speciality 7
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Other name Doctor
        [specialities] => Array
            (
                [1] => Speciality 1
                [6] => Speciality 6
            )

    )

)
```

I would like to create an autocomplete search field for specialties using AJAX,

How could I do it?

Comment: Take a look [Plugin API/Action Reference/wp ajax (action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: Hi! Thank you @manetsus I forgot to close it, I already found a solution.